# Simple javascript issue - list is NOT expanding correctly

Tags: javascript, css, list

The CSS:

```
#divMainMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    height:400px;
}
#divMainMenu li {
    height: 17px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 14px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #eee7cb;
    background: url(../../Images/50pTransparent-20x20.png) repeat;
}
#divMainMenu li ul{
    display: none;
}
```

The html and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Show(pObj)
{
pObj = document.getElementById(pObj).id;
if (document.getElementById(pObj).style.display=='none')
    document.getElementById(pObj).style.display='block';
else
    document.getElementById(pObj).style.display='none';
}
</script>
<div id="divSidePanel">
    <div id="divMainMenu">
        <ul>
            <li onclick="Show('Buyers')">Buyers
                <ul id="Buyers" style="display:none;">
                    <li>Search</li>
                    <li>Submit request</li>
                    <li>Send message to owner</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Sellers</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem:
When I click on the text **Buyers**, it shows the sub/nested list. However, the other items do not make space for the nested list. Thus the nested list writes over the space of the main list.

Is this a problem with my code or is it the standard way it's meant to work? And is there a way to let the other items 'push down' making way for the nested items?

Thanks!

Comment: `pObj = document.getElementById(pObj).id;` - that line makes me facepalm.

Comment: In case you wonder why: If the element does not exist, it will throw an error, if it does exist it is a no-op since it's pretty much equal to ´pObj = pObj´. Use `var elem = document.getElementById(pObj)` and then `elem.style...` in the following code.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I do not intend keeping pObj assigned this way. It was mere work in progress... Anyway, I tried your method as well but stil no change. Also note that even with pObj, when I alert the value of the display property, it DOES show 'none'. So technically it should give out some answer. Also, instead of saying **display=''**, when I write **display='block'** the nested list show but without the expansions.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an answer but just a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this out of  your css:

```
#divMainMenu li ul{
    display: none;
}
```

And change the `height` property to `min-height` on your `#divMainMenu li` selector

Resultant css:

```
#divMainMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    height:400px;
}
#divMainMenu li {
    min-height: 17px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 14px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #eee7cb;
    background: url(../../Images/50pTransparent-20x20.png) repeat;
}
#divMainMenu li ul{

}​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/M5HLD/)

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time on running through this. I also agree that there's no point using a library just for a little thing like this. Unfortunately I could not +1 you on that since your comment was removed. Thanks again!

Comment: And one more thing... I changed **#divMainMenu ul** to **min-height:100px** to prevent it from running out of the div meant for the menu :)

Comment: keep in mind using `#divMainMenu ul` matches all `ul` that are a descendant of `#divMainMenu`. In your situation, that means that both the outside and inside `ul`'s are matched.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `min-height:` instead of `height`: in the CSS.  If you know jQuery, the .hide() and .show() functions will work MUCH better.

Comment: thank you for your advice. This is just one of those moments that I need to keep a very light-weight project. And using JQuery is not an option on this task. But yes, I do agree it has plenty of features - and yes, I have used it as well :) +1 for your advice.

Comment: Thanks for the response and +1.  I tend to use jQuery everywhere, but I understand if you can't.